# Access property of an object from a nested object

Tags: javascript, oop

Let's say we have two constructors like these:

```
function Player(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.hello = function() {
    console.log("Hello, " + this.npc); // World npc property
  }
}

function World() {
  this.player = new Player(0, 0);
  this.npc = "villager";  
}
```

How can i access the npc property of World from the hello function in Player?

**this** doesn't work, since World is not a prototype of Player.

Comment: It seems like you'd want to tell `hello` who it's greeting. Pass it in as a param.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). When used, it will allow you to bind the `this` context from World to the called hello function in Player.

```js
function Player(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.hello = function() {
    alert("Hello, " + this.npc); // World npc property
  }
}

function World() {
  this.player = new Player(0, 0);
  this.npc = "villager";
  this.player.hello.call(this);
}

new World();
```

Comment: I like this, but what if i want to call the function in a second time? I can't make it work apart from the moment i initialize World.

Comment: @Cuz - You would use `world.player.hello.call(world)`. Or you could internalize the hello function call to world since it doesn't have much to do with player. You could have hello expect to take a world object. You could have World inherit the prototype of player and implement its own hello function. There are many options, the one which requires the least amount of change is using `call`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to instantiate the `World` function to make it an object as so:

```
var world = new World();
alert(world.npc);
```

Comment: Yes, that's the way i did, but i would like to know if there's a better way.

Comment: I don't see that in the example you provided. I think you did a great job separating the objects into different classes. I would not do it differently. This way will increase your code's usability.

Answer (score 1):

Pass it as a parameter:

```
function Player(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.hello = function(npc) {
    console.log("Hello, " + npc); // World npc property
  }
}

function World() {
  this.npc = "villager";
  this.player = new Player(0, 0);
  this.player.hello(this.npc);  
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing it to the `Player` constructor?

Comment: This assumes a lot about his desired architecture, but is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
var World = function () {
  this.npc = "villager";
  this.player = new Player(0, 0);  
  return {
    npc: this.npc,
    player: this.player
  };
}();
```

You can now access the `npc` from other contexts using `World.npc`.